# Git Bash: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required, but I already have it installed

Tags: windows, git, visual-c++, line-profiler

I am using git to clone https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler.git on Windows 10. It is erroring out with this error but I have this installed (see image below):

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

This is the command I am using:

```
git clone https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler.git
find line_profiler -name '*.pyx' -exec cython {} \;
cd line_profiler
pip install . --user
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any Visual C++, you only have Redistributable packages. They install run-time libraries that are used to run applications written with VC. But you need Visual C++ compiler! Install [Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017).

See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Comment: Was missing Build Tools. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Build tool, new link at here: https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_BuildTools.exe

[image]